# Binding methods that are properties of a parent object in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I sometimes run into situations where it would be nice to be able to bind methods as an object property instead of a direct Vue method. For example instead of:

```html
<MyInput 
  :formatter="currencyFormat" 
  :parser="currencyParser" 
/>
```

It would be nice to be able do things like:

```html
<MyInput 
  :formatter="formatter.currency.format"
  :parser="formatter.currency.parser" 
/>
```

...and expose just `formatter` from the Vue class instead of writing a thin wrapper method for each case I want to bind. This can generate a lot boilerplate that feels unnecessary.

Is it possible to do this? If so what would the class code look like? Putting an object with methods on it in `data` feels wrong to me.

Comment: It looks fine to me. Reference as any other. What does it throw?

Comment: Not sure what your use case and/or motivation is, but you might want to look into mixins.

Comment: @Tim - how would you use mixins to address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have limited information for my answer. So I am going to do alot of assumptions.

### TLDR

You could have the method return an object and execute it in your template, or use a computed, which returns an object. Both will provide the functionality you want.

### Example (props are functions)

This could look like (and here are my assumptions):

```js
<script>
export default {
  /* other options */
  methods: {
    /* other methods */
    formattter() {
      const format = (value) => new Intl.NumberFormat('nl-NL', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(value);
      const parser = (value) => parseFloat(value);

      return {
        currency: {
          format,
          parser,
        },
      };
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

With the above method, you can indeed do the following in your template:

```js
<MyInput 
  :formatter="formatter().currency.format"
  :parser="formatter().currency.parser" 
/>
```

Your props `formatter` and `parser` will be two functions, as defined in the Object returned.

### Less boilerplate

To avoid even more boilerplate, you can also do the following:

```js
<script>
export default {
  /* other options */
  methods: {
    /* other methods */
    formattter() {
      const formatter = (value) => new Intl.NumberFormat('nl-NL', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(value); // use the same name as your prop 'formatter'
      const parser = (value) => parseFloat(value);

      return {
        currency: {
          formatter, // use the same name as your prop 'formatter'
          parser,
        },
      };
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

And in your template:

```js
<MyInput v-bind="formatter().currency" />
```

This will bind the `formatter.currency.formatter` to your `formatter` prop, and it will also bind the `formatter.currency.parser` to your `parser` prop.

### Value is in parent component

Additionally, if your props in the `MyInput` component need to be values (not functions), and the value which needs to be parsed/formatted is a value in your data option within the parent:

```js
<script>
export default {
  /* other options */
  data() {
    return { 
      /* other data */
      myNumberValue: '9001' // Yes. It's over 9000
    } 
  },
  methods: {
    /* other methods */
    formattter() {
      const value = this.myNumberValue;
      const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('nl-NL', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR', }).format(value);
      const parser = parseFloat(value);

      return {
        currency: {
          formatter,
          parser,
        },
      };
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

---

Does this answer your question?